# jQuery DataTables - Responsive Table with ScrollY is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables plugin with Responsive Table and fixed yScroll and disabling xScroll.

But I am still getting the Horizontal Scrollbar, though I am adding the code like below...

```
scrollY: 200,
scrollX: false,
```

> **Screenshot Ref:**
>   [image]

Anyhow, I am using Responsive table, why I want to show the Horizontal Scrollbar?

**Because of this, Expand / Collapse on Columns functionality also not working...**

Please refer the code, online example and screenshot below...

---

### [Online Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ebp6le8l)

---

> **CSS**

```
th,td{white-space:nowrap;}
```

**If I remove above css it is working as expected. But I dont want to wrap down the td / th text. This is where I am facing problem :(**

> **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'RCT<"clear">lfrtip',

    scrollY: 200,
    scrollX: false,

    columnDefs: [
      { visible: false, targets: 1 }
    ],

    "tableTools": {
      "sRowSelect": "multi",
      "aButtons": [
        {
          "sExtends": "print",
          "sButtonText": "Print"
        }
      ]
    }

  });
});
```

> **HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
.....................
```

Comment: Remove CSS rule `th,td{white-space:nowrap;}` to get rid of horizontal scrolbar.

Comment: **@Gyrocode.com**... Thanks for that.. but some reason, I have to maintain 'nowrap' property in my application **:(**

Comment: Then I'm afraid, it will not be possible. There are other issues with your set-up as well, such as "Position" header shown, click on name cell result both in row select and plus sign open/close, responsive plug-in doesn't seem to work, etc. And it's not recommended to load files from `https://www.datatables.net` where access would be blocked, use `//cdn.datatables.net` instead.

Comment: Yes **@Gyrocode.com**, if I remove white-space property then only expand/collapse is working... :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot change `body{margin:50px;max-width:700px;}` to `body{margin:50px;max-width:900px;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this from:

```
columnDefs: [
  { visible: false, targets: 1 }
],
```

To:

```
columnDefs: [
  { targets: 1 }
],
```

And the horizontal scrollbar goes away.

Working fork:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/qfeibp13

Comment: Thanks **@UncleRico**, Its working like champ...
Awarded **50 points** for your smart answer with Demo... Thanks a LOTTT

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, `targets` marks the num of column where a corresponding option should be applied. So, if you don't need the option, you don't have to specify a `targets`; you just delete the `columnDefs` all. `visible: false` means you want to hide this column in `targets`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `className: 'none'` to your columndefs

```
columnDefs: [
  { className: 'none', targets: 1 }
]
```

Looks to be a conflict between the responsive addon and the visibility hidden option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Responsive, then Responsive will decide the columns visibility. If you don't want the data from a specific column to be shown then use the "never" class as follows.

```
"columnDefs": [ {
    /*"visible": false, <- this does not work with responsive*/
    "className": "never",
    "targets": 0,
    }]
```